# What are the synchronous/asynchronous properties of the mongo shell?

Tags: mongodb, asynchronous

I'm used to JavaScript being non-blocking/async, especially when it comes to IO. That's why the `mongo` shell kind of weirds me out. Take this example from [MongoDb: The Definitive Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449344682):

(from page 31):

---

For example, suppose we insert a million dummy elements with the following:

```
> for (var i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
... db.tester.insert({"foo": "bar", "baz": i, "z": 10 - i}) ... }
```

Now we’ll try to remove all of the documents we just inserted, measuring the time it takes. First, here’s a simple remove:

```
> var timeRemoves = function() {
... var start = (new Date()).getTime();
...
... db.tester.remove();
... db.findOne(); // makes sure the remove finishes before continuing ...
... var timeDiff = (new Date()).getTime() - start;
... print("Remove took: "+timeDiff+"ms");
... }
> timeRemoves()
```

---

See that comment by `db.findOne()`? That's straight from the text. Bumping streams like that isn't totally weird to me, but it's the kind of thing that you don't know about until you spend a long time trying to figure out what's wrong with something you expect to work.

**So, what is the async/sync deal with the `mongo` shell?** How am I supposed to know what to expect, and when and how to bump IO ops like the one above. Is this documented anywhere? Is there any way to get it to work asynchronously, like JS normally behaves? I understand that's weird for a REPL, but still...

Comment: There is no asynchronous action. The reason is for simplicity. The mongo shell is not meant to be a programming environment for applications, it is just a tool. If you want programming features then use a programming language or environment for JavaScript like node.

Comment: @NeilLunn: gotcha. In that case, how am I supposed to know when/how to nudge? Is the above-cited nudge _the_ nudge? Are there others? What  can I expect from this shell runtime!? My question is really about what to expect.

Comment: As I already pointed out, it sounds like you are writing a program. The shell here is just a tool. You can try things out here and get immediate results (or create a blocking loop) and likewise. Everything blocks here as there are no callbacks. If you want to program then use a programming language you like. Drivers are available for just about all of them.

Comment: I'm not writing a program using the shell. I'm doing that with Node. I'm using the shell for data inspection. Anyway, as I've already pointed out, it seems like the shell is _not_ always blocking, given the book excerpt I cite.

Comment: There is nothing in what you have posted that demonstrates "non-blocking". I cannot see how this is productive to future viewers. There actually is no question here other than what you should have been able to work out. It has been stated various times, there is no asynchronous action here". Everything blocks. Write your program in node and be done with it. This doesn't help anyone.

Comment: No, Neil, that is not the case. If the shell is always blocking, why can you not count on the previous command returning being an indication that it is finished? Why does the author of this book include `db.findOne(); // makes sure the remove finishes before continuing ...`? Why do you insist on polluting this comment thread, while ignoring the nature of my question? My question is about the shell. The shell exists as a tool separate from the language bindings, and I'd like to understand its nature. If you do not understand or do not wish to understand the shell, please stop posting here.

Answer (score 6):

I rely on the mongo shell for executing database migrations. The correctness of my migrations are heavily reliant on whether the mongo shell commands are synchronous or asynchronous.

I haven't been able to find anything in the docs  , so I wrote a test script:

```
var ops = [];
var numDocs = 1e5;

var time1 = +new Date();
for (var i = 0; i < numDocs; i++) {
  ops.push({
    insertOne: {
      document: {
        test: 'test',
      }
    }
  });
}
db.test_obj.bulkWrite(ops);
var time2 = +new Date();
var count1 = db.test_obj.count();

db.test_obj.update({}, {$set: {test: 'test2'}}, {multi: true});

var countA = db.test_obj.find({test: 'test'}).count();
var countB = db.test_obj.find({test: 'test2'}).count();
print('Inserting ' + numDocs.toString() + ' documents took: ' + ((time2 - time1) / 1000).toString() + 's');
print(count1);
print(countA);
print(countB);
```

Output:

```
> mongo --host <HOST> test-2.js
<MONGO INIT OUTPUT>
Inserting 100000 documents took: 16.258s
100000
0
100000
```

**From this I gather that all operations in mongo shell are synchronous** -- although there are no such guarantees! There might be some operations that aren't synchronous or some conditions in my script making it appear synchronous.

The logic is that if e.g. `.bulkWrite()` or `.update()` were async the `.count()` call afterwards would return a number lower than 100,000. However, another possible explanation is that `.count()` is playing catch-up, looping over the collection as the documents are being inserted/updated.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this question concerning the sync vs async nature of the `mongo` shell can be understood by something the author writes later on in the book:

---

> [The shell] does unacknowledged writes and then checks that the last operation was successful before drawing the prompt. Thus, if you do a series of invalid operations on a collection, finishing with a valid operation, the shell will not complain:

```
> db.foo.insert({"_id" : 1}); db.foo.insert({"_id" : 1}); db.foo.count()
1
```

> You can manually force a check in the shell by calling getLastError, which checks for an error on the last operation:

```
> db.foo.insert({"_id" : 1}); db.foo.insert({"_id" : 1}); print(
... db.getLastError()); db.foo.count()
E11000 duplicate key error index: test.foo.$_id_  dup key: { : 1.0 }
1
```

> This can be helpful when scripting for the shell.

---

Ah, ha—so the shell REPL achieves synchronous behavior because its operations are unacknowledged.